# How are CDS prices calculated for financial institutions?

Tags: credit-risk, cds, default

If you need to estimate the fair price of a credit default swap on a financial institution, can it be done? Typical structural models tend to break down for the complex debt and asset characteristics of a financial institution. How do traders value CDSs for firms like JP Morgan?

Comment: It's not just the CDS. It is difficult to understand and analyze the SIFIs and *all* their securities because of their complexity and lack of transparency.

Comment: so if I wanted to price a one-year CDS for a financial firm, is there no real way to go about doing this? I can get pretty accurate for standard industrial firms.